# exported environment variables not available in intellij tests on unix

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

When running SBT in a terminal, the variables exported in my `~/.bashrc` file are visible to my Scala tests (`sbt testQuick`)

> e.g. `export MY_PASSWORD=123abc` from `.bashrc` is visible when calling `sys.env.getOrElse("MY_PASSWORD","notthepassword")`

However when I run the same test using Intellij's builtin run/test configurations, I am unable to resolve these variables.

---

I have seen an option to set environment variables for tests in the run configurations but there are two problems I have with this method:

1. I do not wish to place plain-text passwords in here
2. I have to set up the variables everytime i create a new test to run (I would like to simply `right-click` -> `run test` without worrying about setting variables that should be available for my tests).

I'm exhausted from searching and hope someone already knows the answer.

Kind regards,
coderatchet.

Comment: Launch IntelliJ from the shell after it reads your bashrc. Otherwise, if launching it from your desktop environment, then you must set the variable in a location where your DE will know about it

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm not sure what you mean about "a location where your DE will know about it". I've tried adding the line `source ~/.bashrc` to the `idea.sh` file, however this still does not work.